1970s supernatural thriller featuring a black dog
I've been trying to recall the name of a film I saw a couple of times long ago.
It's a supernatural thriller, but I don't remember much of the plot. A black dog, likely named Nosferatu, featured. The dog carried some association with evil, and there was some sort of cult, possibly religious, associated with it.
The filming locations have a Mediterranean feel, possibly Greece or Middle East, although the film could have been shot anywhere at a similar latitude.

What was supernatural about the film?

There was some religious cult associated with this dog. The presence of the dog somehow indicated something evil. It's all a bit vague.

Hmmm. Was the black dog used to hunt people? Could the cult-like aspect you recall be related to the villain being possessed by his bloodthirsty ancestor?

I ask because there are several Eurohorror films from the 70s with black dogs.

As I recall the black dog was an independent presence. It would show up on its own. I don't remember it being used, as such. The key to the black dog is the name. I distinctly remember it being called Nosferatu (memory is always fallible, though). I don't think this was a Eurohorror film. The locations had a Mediterranean feel, but the film had the production feel of other contemporary horror - think 'The Reincarnation of Peter Proud'

Hmmm. Perhaps ZOLTAN - HOUND OF DRACULA (1977)?

There is also a USA tv movie Devil Dog: The Hound of Hell (1978)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_Dog:_The_Hound_of_Hell  But if your memory is accurate it wouldn't be the one you ask about.

Perhaps "Daughters of Satan" from 1972? The movie was partially filmed in the Philippines, and included a black dog named Nicodemus. Tom Selleck starred.

@cassfrank also known as Dracula's dog https://youtu.be/yY61Hy6HNL8?si=ILRH2HEKjsHBMZqp

@stanleywebb has it. Daughters of Satan is exactly the film. The dogs name was a red herring. It was the only part of the film I was sure I recalled accurately, but I was wildly adrift. The Spanish influence in the Phlippines matches 'Mediterranean feel'. I had intended to find the film and watch it again, but having seen clips on YouTube and elsewhere I wonder if it has stood the test of time. Thanks Stanley. Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

This movie is "Daughters of Satan", from 1972. One of Tom Selleck's early roles. The plot involves ancient witches burned at the stake in a painting, and the appearance of a large, black dog named Nicodemus. The film was partially shot in the Philippines. The painted witches somehow possess a modern host, or reincarnate themselves out of the painting.
I'll include a cover image, and a link to the film's Wikipedia article.


This sounds very much like "The Omen" (1976) though the dog is never given a specific name in this version (not that I remember anyway). It is also mainly set in the United Kingdom though there are several scenes shot in Italy, possibly giving it the Mediterranean feel you remember. It was an American budgeted and directed movie (Richard Donner) which would have made it look contemporary.
There was a 2006 remake that also included a black dog and a bit more of the movie was shot around the Mediterranean (Italy and Israel). Maybe you've seen both versions and merged the locations together to give it more of a Mediterranean feel?

Definitely not The Omen. I have seen the version with Gregory Peck and Lee Remick and remember the plot well. I first saw my film decades before the remake of The Omen was released, and I haven't seen the remake.
